# Apply jQuery on an element that has stopPropagation and/or preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Project link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/wp/ziva/?page_id=7
```

I have applied owl-carousel on the page to display products. The layout is like this:

[image]

When a user hovers over the product, a white overlay would slideDown, and the layout would be like this:

[image]

I am applying the following JS:

```
$('.owl-item .item').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('.itemHover').animate({
        top:0,
        opacity:1
        }, 700)
    setTimeout(function () {    

    $(this).find('.dressName, .dressLinks').animate({
        top:0,
        opacity:1
        },500)
    }, 501);

})
```

But it isn't working. It is most likely because of the multiple stopPropagation and or the preventDefault functions in the owl-carousel plugin. Is there any way to apply the jQuery that I want, on the products?

Link to the plugin's js:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/wp/ziva/wp-content/themes/ziva/js/owl.carousel.js
```

Comment: Applying your JS in console of firebug works. Aren't You missing $(function(){
Your code here 
});
In your js file?

Comment: This is called inside the document ready function, I will try your method, give me a minute.

Comment: Do you want an approach with CSS?

Comment: No change after putting it inside that as well.

Comment: @Matheus, if there is no way to do it with jQuery, then sure, please let me know. Will it have some animation/transition to it?

Comment: @Harmeet I don't know about js, but i'll see if i can do something with css

Comment: I'm trying to have a look but I get an error: "NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable - http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/wp/ziva/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", I don't if this is the problem, but it does prevent looking for an answer. I cannot imagine anything in your piece of code would conflict with eventpropagation or preventdefault accept for the hover, but this is easily detected with a console.log().

Comment: you are missing SEMICOLONS and also, code is not correct. CSS also needs to be done

Comment: @STEEL Yeah, i've answered but css still looks unfinished. Yet that is not related to the question

Comment: Delegation worked. @STEEL, css and semicolons were not an issue here, but thanks to everybody who commented here, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `delegation` using `on`, my be the elements are not ready at the time code is run

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.owl-item .item',function(){

});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.owl-item .item',function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you put this code below on index.css, you will have your hover effect with CSS.

```
.item:hover>.itemHover {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover>.itemHover>.dressName {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover>.itemHover>.dressLinks {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do those animations through css3 transitions (Not supported in IE8 and below).
The only difference is that in those old browsers the animation is not going to show up, but the functionality is going to work as expected.

Add the following css rules to your css file:

```
.itemHover {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.owl-item:hover .itemHover {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```